# Can you great people help me create a certain bassline please ! Thanks in advance :

Tags: sound-design

Looking to create these types of bass in these tracks.

It can be in any VST really. But at the moment i'm using, massive, sylenth 1, albino, alchemy, vstation and zebra.

I always end up giving up and i've been trying to produce for years..
I've tried with squares, sines, saws. Tried using an envelope on the cuttoff and bringing the cuttoff down but I'm rubbish at this... I dont know how to use distortion proper or compression either..
Need some advice on how to create these sounds... That would be amazing...
I could even pay if someone could recreate it for me..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @TimPost
This is NOT SSD Sound design. But it IS Musial sound design. A very clear cut example of what SSD users don't want. Sorry TheAnimal for using your question as an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is a psytrance/trance bassline. Simple ad envelope on lowpass filter and amp. 90% that makes this sound is the bassline is the combination of bass + kickdrum. Either have a Short kick with a bassheavy bass or have a long bass kick with a lighter bass.

For further questions concerning this theme you better go to a edm oriented forum and not to a sound design based forum. Most users of SSD work with game and movie sound design rather than musik.

Good Day

PS it's saw waves, so sylenth1 should work.

Comment: ..........pSytrance?

Comment: Yeah iphone "corrects" everything! -.-

Comment: i did google "paytrance". impossible to stay on top of genres these days, i thought :D